# How exactly does Url Encoding work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, encoding

In MVC, I'm attempting to use URL routing to get the result of an action given a certain input.

Consider the following in my view:

`<%=Html.ActionLink("View", "Test", new with {.id = Url.Encode(dir\file}) %>`

My controller then uses `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(id)` to get the original. The controller itself is using `File()` to retrieve a file at the specified directory\file location. However, an error message pops up telling me that

`A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).`

The URL is showing up as

`http://home/dir%255cfile.txt`

I googled Url Encoding and `\` is encoded as `%5c`. Where is the %25 coming from? It's the encoding for %, but that means Encode is being done twice. Why is that, and is that supposed to be happening?

Answer (score 1):

`Html.ActionLink` takes care of the URL encoding for you. If you don't encode the params there, there's no need to decode it again and your issue is solved.